# C# compiler type inference difference between inline method call and separate method call

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, type-inference

It seems like the C# compiler infers types differently depending on how a method is called:

```
void Foo<T>() where T : Bar
{
   var instance = new T()
   {
      ID = 1
   }.
   ExtensionMethod();
}
```

In this case the compiler seems to infer that the type of instance is Bar, because I have a class Bar where ExtensionMethod is declared.

```
void Foo<T>() where T : Bar
{
   var instance = new T()
   {
      ID = 1
   };
   instance.ExtensionMethod();
}
```

In this case the compiler infers that the type of instance is T, which is what I would expect it to do in the first case as well.
Why is there such a difference?

Comment: The `.` operator has very high precedence, and the assignment operator `=` has a very low one. See [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx). Therefore, in your first example, instance is set to all of `( new T() { ID = 1}.ExtensionMethod() )`. It's like the difference between `var inst = (A.B);` and `(var inst = A).B;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you assign the result of the method call to instance. In the second case you discard the call's result. Instead, you assign the `new T` This is the only difference.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `var` keyword definition in [Implicitly Typed Local Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) :

> The var keyword instructs the compiler to infer the type of the
>   variable from the expression on the right side of the initialization
>   statement

On the *right* side of the `var`,in your case, there is **not only** the `ctor` part, but also a function call, which returns void. So it turns out in *infering* the type assignable to `var` from `void` returned by the function call. This leads to a *compiler* signal about a fact:

*Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable*